# Java - Converting a generic class' instance to specialized class' instance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am struggling with the most fundamental concept of OOP in Java.

```
class Person {}

class Parent extends Person {}
```

All parents are people, but not all people are parents.

```
Person adam  = new Person();
adam  = new Parent(); // but this just means that the variable 'adam' is just referencing a completely new object.
adam = (Parent)adam; // java.lang.ClassCastException
```

how do you express the idea of *becoming a subclass* in Java? Does one just have to write a constructor for the subclass that takes a superclass object for example...

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

and now the parent class would look like:

```
public class Parent extends Person {
    public Parent(Person p) {
        super(p.getName());
    }
}
```

output:

```
public class Run {

    public static <T> void display(T x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person adam  = new Person("adam");

        display(adam instanceof Person); // true
        display(adam instanceof Parent); // false

        // now lets assume that adam has had a child. 
        // adam has 'become' a parent. He is still also a person.

        adam = new Parent(adam);

        display(adam instanceof Person); // true
        display(adam instanceof Parent); // true
    }
}
```

Is this the only way? Is there are better way? How does one express the idea of *becoming* in Java. That is to say, starting off with a reference to a *general* object, and becoming more specialized.

** edit for clarification:

let us assume we have a class **T**

let us assume we have a variable *v* of type **T** (*v* :: **T**)

we set *v* to reference a new object of type **T**.

```
T v = new T();
```

(*v* :: **T**) -> (*obj-t* :: **T**)

we have a class **S** that is a subclass of type **T**. It may or may not have additional methods.

I would like to create a new object *obj-s* of type **S** that copies all of the information (instance variables) from *obj-t*.

allowing me to use the existing variable (*v* :: **T**) to refer to the new object.

```
v = new S(v);
```

(*v* :: **T**) -> (*obj-s* :: **S**)

thus *obj-s* is an instance of both **S** and **T**, and the use of *v* is valid as **S** is a subclass of **T**.

My question was if my method was correct?

Comment: Your argument makes sense.  I think thats the right way

Comment: If your model requires that an object starts off as a general `X` (e.g. `Person`), and becomes a more specific `Y` (e.g. `Parent`), then it probably is not a good situation to use inheritance, because as you observe, you can't change an object's type at run-time.

Comment: Objects don't _become_ anything, thry just _are_.

Comment: @Themanontheclapham Poor Adam still can't be a `Parent` without you telling it to be a `Parent` (through a cast).

Comment: @khelwood - are there particular design patterns that are more appropriate?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus It depends what you are trying to gain by having a `Parent` class. If it is simply "I want to track that a person is or isn't a parent", then you could have a boolean field. Inheritance is not the solution to every problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider the thing you're trying to do as a sort of [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) like PHP uses; the 'reference type' can be changed at runtime.
Java, in contrast, uses [typed variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). You define a reference which you call *something*, that is, the variable name, with in our case the type `Person`. Now you can so to speak 'link' an object to the variable name. That object can be of any type, as long as it is of type `Person`.

With the code `adam = new Parent()`, you assign the variable `adam` (which is of type `Person`, exactly as you declared it) to the new `Parent` instance. Note that the object previously referred to as `adam` (the one you created with `new Person()`), is still in the memory, but has no reference to it. Once the [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) comes by, the object is erased from memory.
Once you declare a reference `adam` with type `Person`, you cannot *redefine* the variable `adam` to have the type `Parent`. The reference `adam` always has the type `Person`, once you declare it that way.

If you know for sure that the object your reference `adam` is actually pointing to is of type `Parent`, you can cast it safely:

```
((Parent) adam).doSomethingOnlyParentsWouldDo();
((Parent) adam).raiseChild();
```

Alternatively, you can assign the object of reference `adam` to a new variable of that subtype, like this:

```
Parent padam = (Parent) adam;
padam.doSomethingOnlyParentsWouldDo();
padam.raiseChild();
```

---

If you just want to copy the information or any person into a `Parent` class, you must create a copy constructor:

```
public Parent(Person person) {
    // Assuming fields are protected
    this.prop = person.prop;
    this.anotherProp = person.prop;
}
```

or just a static creator method:

```
public static Parent createFromPerson(Person person) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    // Assuming fields are protected
    this.prop = person.prop;
    this.anotherProp = person.prop;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: for example if they were in a array

Comment: but TBH it is more about fully understanding the type system.

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus What exactly are you trying to achieve? Which design pattern you should apply, depends on what you want.

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus And, is my answer clear about references (and their types) and actual objects (and their types)?

Comment: I have a uni exam... they ask some really odd questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible in Java. Once an object is created as a certain type, it remains that type for the remainder of its lifetime. So if you create a `Parent`, you can refer to it as an `Object`, a `Person`, or a `Parent`, but underneath it will *always* be a `Parent`, and that cannot be changed after the object is created.

Comment: exactly, but if it is "becoming" a subclass then this is fine surely?

Comment: If you have a `Person` reference to an object that you know is really a `Parent`, then you can *cast* it to a `Parent`, but that's not actually changing the object (the object isn't "becoming" anything); it's simply changing your *view* of the object.

Comment: when I tried casting I was getting errors... `adam = (Parent)adam;` results in java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: Right. If Adam was *actually* a parent (`adam = new Parent()`), then there would be no `ClassCastException`. But if Adam is really just a person (`adam = new Person()`), then you can't cast it to (view it as) a parent, because it *isn't* really a parent.

Comment: I think I just find it confusing when both `adam = new Parent(adam)` and `adam = (Parent)adam` are both considered casts!

Comment: They're not. `new Parent(adam)` is (roughly) a _copy_ operation - it creates a new `Parent` that is a copy of `adam`. `(Parent)adam` is a cast - it fails if `adam` is not already a `Parent`. (I say "roughly" a copy because `adam` may not have been a `Parent` to begin with. In fact, he may have been some other subclass of `Person`.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't make sense of your idea of "becoming." You created an object whose type is a derived class, and access it through a variable that is of the base class's type. Nothing becomes anything in this scenario- the object's contents are unchanged. Similarly, the constructor only uses an object as an argument to guide what contents the resulting object should have. That object could be of any type.

Also, a cast does not change object contents, either.

Are you trying to create a copy-constructor?

Comment: I created an object that is the base class. the variable is of type base class. I then want to change the object to a subclass (copy-constructor?) while still using the same variable to reference it. I think this is what I have done no?

Comment: You cannot "change" an object from one class to the other, even if their classes are related. It sounds like you want to make a copy-constructor, which simply uses data from one object to initialize another one.

Comment: 'create a new object' of type subclass that copies the instance variable of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, inheritance does not allow you to
make one object become something else. What you are trying to do might
better be implemented as an attribute. This is also a very flexible
solution as you can easily add other attributes.

```
class Person {
  private boolean isParent;
  // ...
}
```

If you want to be more flexible, you could implemented a very simple
attribute system like this:

```
abstract class Attribute { }
class ParentAttribute extends Attribute {
  java.utils.ArrayList<Person> children;
}
class Person {
  java.utils.ArrayList<Attribute> attributes;
  public void setAttribute(Attribute attr) {
    // If an attribute of the same type as attr already exists,
    // replace it.
    // ...
  }
  public <T> T getAttribute() {
    // Find an attribute by the class T or return null.
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `isParent`.